# Can a wireless headphone contain malware which can infect an Android device?

Tags: malware, android, bluetooth

I go to conferences and there are often free bluetooth earbuds and headsets given away.

If I pair them with an Android device, is it possible for them to infect the phone with a virus?

I have read some other posts which talked about security of the bluetooth connection to the device. However I am worried more about the possibility of malware on the headphone and the malware being transmitted to the Android phone (Android 9.0).

I would appreciate any thoughts on whether this would be easy for someone to do or is fairly difficult.

There is a question about whether a bluetooth stereo could infected with malware and spread it to a phone.

However my question is different. Is it possible for the HARDWARE manufacturer of the bluetooth headphones to embed malware which can spread to an Android 9.0 device? I am trying to understand how likely and how difficult this would be.

Comment: Just a reminder, when you are pairing an untrusted audio device with your phone, make sure it connects as a speaker or headphones, not as a keyboard or disk.

Comment: Similar to : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169332/can-a-compromised-car-stereo-spread-vulnerability-to-a-connected-phone-via-bluet/212048#212048